# How can I input data automatically in a continuous data?

Tags: google-sheets, continuous

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbTuc.jpg)
How can I input data in column F with 4 consecutive data for each data like column E using the data in column D2:D?

Is it possible?

How should I modify the formula in F2?
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MOD(ROW(F2:F)-1,4)>0,{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D;D2:D},""))`
Let me know if you have any other questions.

If I input data in column B , set consecutive data for each data in F2:F like E2:E.

Comment: So just to confirm, what you would want to achieve is if there are 4 or more duplicate data on Col E that matches on Col D, it would output the results on Col F, is that correct?

Comment: thanks for your help.  If you click the "enter image description here" in my text, you can check the sheet image.